# Catching reorder event on magento

Tags: magento, events

I need to remove a product from an order, when the reorder button is clicked in magento's admin panel.

ATM I'm using `sales_order_save_after` in the `global` node. It fires on completed, cancelled and alike events - but not on reorder.

```
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <isThisTagTotallyRandom>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                    <method>onOrderSaved</method>
                </isThisTagTotallyRandom>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
```

So my questions are:

- what would be the correct event for catching reorders?
- after all, on reorder, there should be a save action sometime, why is this event not called?
- as a bonus questions: Is the tag `<isThisTagTotallyRandom>` really totally random?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a reorder is made, only a quote is created first. This explains why no order is saved so far.

If you look at reorder action from `Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_CreateController` it calls `initFromOrder` from `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create`. In this method there's an event called `sales_convert_order_to_quote` that is dispatched and that you can listen to. You can get the quote and order from it (and remove a product from it).

At this point only a quote is created that will be converted to order when Submit Order button is clicked (at this point you can react to `sales_order_save_after` I guess).

Comment: btw: If you have a sec ... is it true what I stated about the `<isThisTagTotallyRandom>` Tag?

Comment: I can't explain the deep reason about it but yeah the layout handle `isThisTagTotallyRandom` can be anything you want and it wont make any difference.